# Simple Common Factor query

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

if $a|b$ and $a|c$, does it mean that $b|c$?

Comment: No. Let $b=ak$, $c=am$ with $k>m\ge 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, consider $3|9$ and $3|15$ but $9$ does not divide $15$.

Comment: is there any way to link the two together with a common divisor? GCD not known? Because I want to show $b|c$ and only have that information? For example $b|kc$ where $k$ is an integer?

Comment: Yes you can say that $a|b$ and $a|c$ implies $a|gcd(b,c)$.  That's about the best you can say.

Comment: I see, i have edit my comment a little bit can u inform what u think?

Comment: I'm afraid the most you can possibly conclude if all you know is $a|b$ and $a|c$ is that $a|gcd(b,c)$.  You would need more information to say something stronger than that.

Comment: ok, thank u v much

Comment: You're welcome :-)

Comment: $a\mid b$ and $a\mid c$ is equivalent to $a\mid \gcd(b,c)$ (not only implied).

Comment: @user236182 Ok true.

Answer (score 0):

No, for example $2|6$ and $2|10$ but $6\nmid10$.